# Not able to call a javascript function through alert

Tags: c#, jquery, alert, javascript

I am creating an alert and trying to call a click event through javascript function when "OK" of alert is pressed.It runs pretty well if I create the alert on page_Load but When I crate the alert on clicking of a buttton, then on pressing "OK" of alert the required click event is not called.

This is how I create the alert

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Startup", "Test();", true);
    }
```

This is the javascript function which calls a click event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function Test() {
              alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');
              document.getElementById('btnReview').click();
          }
      </script>
```

Comment: try `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` instead of `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: can you set breakpoint on line `document.getElementById('btnReview').click();` and watch value of `document.getElementById('btnReview')`?

Answer (score 1):

if `btnReview` is server button then try change you script like this

for asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function Test() {
          alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');
          document.getElementById('<%= btnReview.ClientID %>').click();
      }
  </script>
```

for asp.net mvc (razor)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function Test() {
          alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');
          document.getElementById('@btnReview.ClientID').click();
      }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          string scripts = @"
          function Test() {

            alert('There is no Bookmarked Question Available');

          }";
          ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Startup", scripts, true);
 }
```

Comment: It does not open any alert

Answer (score 0):

You just add below code in javascript function

```
__doPostBack('btnSubmit','OnClick');
```

Comment: It gives the following error----

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

etccccc